# When looking through a telescope at the moon, do I see it at a more recent time point than with my naked eye?

Tags: optics, speed-of-light

I’m not physics-minded so sorry for the poorly worded question. If I look at the Moon from Earth, my understanding is I am seeing the Moon from around 1 second in the past. But if I also look at it zoomed, am I seeing it only 0.5 seconds in the past or does it not make a difference because it would be zooming from the same place?

Would love to know the maths and logistics of this!

Comment: Its a good question to ask

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. I really like your thinking, Vicky, but zooming does not really get you closer to the object you are looking at.

Comment: After hearing everyone’s answers I understand how simple the question really was. Thank you for delicacy with answering my obvious question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you look at the Moon, be it with your naked eyes or through a telescope, you receive the light that was scattered from the lunar surface about one second ago, and then propagated to you (this propagation is what took this one second).

Telescope zoom then manipulates this light to make the image larger. It takes negligible time for this manipulation to happen (and it applies to the light that has already come from the Moon), so you're watching basically the same time point as you would with your naked eyes.

Comment: Well, with a big reflector telescope (by amateur standards) the path length might be 30cm or so longer than the direct. Which means that the telescope imaging is behind the naked eye by about a nanosecond.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty ... and it's nine orders of magnitude smaller than the delay due to propagation from the Moon to the Earth.